# jQuery Serialize Data producing strange output

Tags: jquery, serialization

I have a strange problem that I am not able to wrap my head around. Now this is just test code that will eventually be implemented but for now, for the sake of the enormous code I have already written out I will just paste a small snippet that is the problem child.

```
//-----
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#postdatabutton').click(function()
    {
        $.post('post_data.php',$('#postform').serialize(), function(data)
        {
            $('#new_submitted_data').prepend(data).fadeIn(333);
        });
    });
});
//----
```

Pretty simple code, using "serialize()" I am sending data to a .php page then using MySQL to insert the submitted $_POST[''] data from a form, but when the data gets inserted, the data (just a small string for example) gets outputted like this:

```
H

E

L

L

o

.

I

a

m

a

s

t

r

i

n

g

.
```

Comment: Most probably you have problems in the backend script.

Comment: Can you log the data, `console.log(data);`

Comment: inspect the request in a browser console and see what is being sent. If by some strange chance it is incorrect...likely a problem in form, else most likely a server code issue

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am 99% confident in my php scripting as I have been writing in php for long time. What it seems to me, and i have segregated this problem code apart from my other code, that serialize() is the issue. It is like it is creating newlines, but revealing the source code of the page does NOT show the "\n".

Comment: @Eric: Please post your solution as an answer below and mark it as accepted.

Comment: OK I figured out what it was. I was using the Latest Development version of jQuery (247 KB). Boy I guess they mean what they say about it being for Development only, it ouputs some strange stuff. Anyways I switched it for kicks to the min version, and the output is now as expected. Thanks for the replies. We can mark this as solved. Thanks again.

Comment: @Colin, I am not seeing any links/buttons/ and/or markings to mark this solution resolved, or accepted.

Comment: @Eric: You must post an actual answer, below. These are simply comments to the original question. You might want to [look over the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) briefly, or [see this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) in particular